# How to push data in multi dimensional array format

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have array of objects declared as below, I want to push data into this using for loop, Lets assume I have two main products and that product has qty and code so I cant provide data I just need to know how to push in below array.

```
var hashtable = [];
var hashtable = [{
    recurrence_code:'',
    products:[{
                    code:'',
                    qty:''
                }],
    start_date:'',
    payment_type:'',
    payment_method:''
}];

for (var i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < 2; j++) {
        hashtable[i].recurrence_code = i;//dumy data
        hashtable[i].products[j].code =j;//dumy data
        hashtable[i].products[j].qty = j;//dumy data
        hashtable[i].start_date = i;//dumy data
        hashtable[i].payment_type = 'pay_as_you_go';
        hashtable[i].payment_method = 'sms2_pay_and_email';             
    }
}
console.log(hashtable);
```

but the above loop structure is not working for me, how can i push data? any help?
After pushing above data into array it should look like this
**output**

```
hashtable[0][recurrence_code] = 0;
 hashtable[0][products][0][code] = 0;
 hashtable[0][products][0][qty] = 0;
 hashtable[0][products][1][code] = 1;
 hashtable[0][products][1][qty] = 1;
 hashtable[0][start_date] = 0;
 hashtable[0][payment_type] = 'pay_as_you_go';
 hashtable[0][payment_method] = 'sms2_pay_and_email';

hashtable[1][recurrence_code] = 0;
hashtable[1][products][0][code] = 0;
hashtable[1][products][0][qty] = 0;
hashtable[1][products][1][code] = 1;
hashtable[1][products][1][qty] = 1;
hashtable[1][start_date] = 0;
hashtable[1][payment_type] = 'pay_as_you_go';
hashtable[1][payment_method] = 'sms2_pay_and_email';
```

This the fiddle to try [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y26nco8y/)

Comment: You want to push product 2 to subscription array???

Comment: Both 1 and 2 I wnat to push to subscription so that I can pass that array to my api, but I need same format.

Comment: This doesn't looks like a proper way to hold data, usually you need to go with something like an array of objects and each object has some properties like ```[{code: '', products:[],start_date:''...},{code: '', products:[],start_date:''...}]```

Comment: then you can create however I need to get that format only

Comment: Somebody please let me know how to loop that data in array

Comment: Regarding the update - how do you add items to `hashtable`? from the error it looks like there is no item in `products[j]`. Do you use `push` to add items? in Java script you can't just refer an item at arbitrary location if it wasn't defined yet. Pleas add more code so we can have a better understanding of what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the edits to the question, here is an example on how to achieve what you are looking for.

There are some errors in the question and in the desired output, for instance the nested `for` loop run 4 times, yet the expected output is only of 2 elements. I assume that is due to lack of understanding of `push` and I have build my example based on the assumption that you want 2 products in each `hashtable` item.

```
//this is class that will build items for the hashtable var.
function HashItem(recurrence_code, start_date, payment_type, payment_method) {
    //these are class vars - they will hold data for each instance of the class
    this.recurrence_code = recurrence_code;
    this.products = [];
    this.start_date = start_date;
    this.payment_type = payment_type;
    this.payment_method = payment_method;

    //this is a class function to add products
    this.add_product = function (prod) {
        //here we push product into the products array
        this.products.push(prod);
    }
};

//this is an other class. It will hold products.
function Product(code, qty) {
    this.code = code;
    this.qty = qty;
}

//this is the hashtable you want to add data to. hashtable may not be appropriate name here...
var hashtable = [];

//here we create 2 items
for (var i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {
    //lets create a new item
    var new_item = new HashItem(i,i,'pay_as_you_go','sms2_pay_and_email');
    //we now create 2 products per item
    for (var j=0; j < 2; j++) {
        //lets create new product
        var new_product = new Product(j,j);
        //and add it to the hash item
        new_item.add_product(new_product);
    }
    //now, we need to push the new item into the hashtable.
    hashtable.push(new_item);
}

//JSON.stringify will convert out class to JSON string. Useful to send it to the back-end API if needed.
//Note that angularjs can just take the object as is in $http calls and will convert it to JSON by itself
console.log(JSON.stringify(hashtable));
```

This will output:

```
[
    {
        "recurrence_code": 0,
        "products": [
            {
                "code": 0,
                "qty": 0
            },
            {
                "code": 1,
                "qty": 1
            }
        ],
        "start_date": 0,
        "payment_type": "pay_as_you_go",
        "payment_method": "sms2_pay_and_email"
    },
    {
        "recurrence_code": 1,
        "products": [
            {
                "code": 0,
                "qty": 0
            },
            {
                "code": 1,
                "qty": 1
            }
        ],
        "start_date": 1,
        "payment_type": "pay_as_you_go",
        "payment_method": "sms2_pay_and_email"
    }
]
```

The form can repeat on the `hashtable` array and it can be sent as is to the back-end API.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Bravo nice one, I will accept your answer but also I will update my solution... but really thanks because of people like you there is always help available here.

Answer (score 0):

so the proble was, subscriptions[i] was not defined inside the loop, so i just re declared it inside the loop :-) thanks to one of best friends helped me in figuring this out. Here is what I got, it may help someone. Cheers

```
var hashtable = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {
                if (!hashtable[i]) {
        hashtable[i] = [];
     }
    hashtable[i].start_date = i;//dummy data
    hashtable[i].recurrence_code = i;//dummy data
    hashtable[i].payment_type = 'pay_as_you_go';
    hashtable[i].payment_method = 'sms2_pay_and_email';
    for (var j=0; j < 2; j++) {
                if (!hashtable[i].products) {
                hashtable[i].products = [];
        }
       if (!hashtable[i].products[j]) {
                hashtable[i].products[j] = [];
        }
        hashtable[i].products[j].code =j;//dummy data
        hashtable[i].products[j].qty = j;//dummy data
    }
}
console.log(hashtable);
```